# Two different implementations

Tags: java, class, filter, program-entry-point, implementation

I want to do two different implementations of a filter, which returns only those students who have at least 50% of the points. My problem is how to implement both methods correctly and in the first I don't understand why it doesn't work and therefore I need your help for that.

The filter class with both implementations:

```
package u7a1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Filter implements IFilter {
    public ArrayList filterRaw(ArrayList groups)
    {
        ArrayList<Boolean> allstudents = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList pass = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++)
        {
            if ((Integer)groups.get(i) >= 50) allstudents.add(true);
            else allstudents.add(false);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); ++i)
        {
            if ((Boolean)allstudents.get(i) == true) pass.add(groups.get(i));
        }
        return pass;
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> filterGeneric(ArrayList<ArrayList<Student>> groups)
    {
        ArrayList<Boolean> allstudents = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList pass = new ArrayList();
        /*for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++)
        {
            Integer mystudentpoints = new Integer(0);
            mystudentpoints = Student.getPoints();
            if (Student.getPoints() >= 50) allstudents.add(true);
            else allstudents.add(false);
        }*/
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); ++i)
        {
            if ((Boolean)allstudents.get(i) == true) pass.add(groups.get(i));
        }
        return pass;
    }
}
```

The filter factory is already correct:

```
package u7a1;

/**
 * Factory for "Testat" filters 
 */
public class FilterFactory {
    /**
     * Create a "Testat" filter
     * @return a "Testat" filter
     */
    public static IFilter create()
    {
        // TODO
        return new Filter();
    }
}
```

Here is the Interfaces which is implemented by the class where the methods aren't working correctly:

```
package u7a1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Filters for students who obtain the "Testat".
 * 
 * The requirements for the testat are to have at least {@link IFilter#criteria} percent 
 * of {@link IFilter#maxNumberofPoints} points.
 */
public interface IFilter {
    public final int maxNumberofPoints = 80;
    public final double criteria = 50;

    /**
     * Filter all students that achieved enough points for the "Testat".
     * 
     * @param groups an ArrayList of groups, where a group is an ArrayList of students
     * @return the ArrayList of all students who achieved enough points for the "Testat".
     */
    public ArrayList filterRaw(ArrayList groups);

    /**
     * Filter all students that achieved enough points for the "Testat".
     * 
     * @param groups an ArrayList of groups, where a group is an ArrayList of students
     * @return the ArrayList of all students who achieved enough points for the "Testat".
     */
    public ArrayList<Student> filterGeneric(ArrayList<ArrayList<Student>> groups);
}
```

I don't edit the main class further than that:

```
/**
 * Main class of the Java program. 
 * 
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-- Array-Listen und Generics --");
        /* you can make function calls from here*/
    }
}
```

Finally I have the Student class which doesn't need any change:

```
package u7a1;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int legi;
    private int points;

    public Student(String name, int legi)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.legi = legi;
        points = 0;
    }

    public int getLegi()
    {
        return this.legi;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Student setPoints(int points)
    {
        this.points = points;
        return this;
    }

    public int getPoints()
    {
        return points;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s (%d)", name, legi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to implement 2 types of filtering rows the strategy design pattern will help u this is a good article http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html
and i think you have to change the fillerrow like

```
  public ArrayList filterRaw(ArrayList groups)
{
    ArrayList pass = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((Integer)groups.get(i) >= 50) pass.add(groups.get(i));

    }
    return pass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project's core is a Main.class, there is everything what will be executed. Other classes are only declared, but they are never used. When you run program it starts lines with commands in main method. Currently the only thing you have there is printing to a console String with text: "-- Array-Listen und Generics --"

Now you need to prepare some data that you will filter, for example

```
Student student1 = new Student("John", 1);
student1.setPoints(51);
Student student2 = new Student("Alice", 2);
student1.setPoints(48);

List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
studentList.add(student1, student2);
```

Let's say that you have test data, now you need to use your filter
To use your filter we need to use its implementation

```
IFilter myFilter = FilterFactory.create();
```

Now myFilter is an instance of your implementation, to use it you need to call a method with declared data

```
List<Student> result = myFilter.filterRaw(studentList);
```

And example implementation of that method would be

```
public List<Student> filteredStudents(List<Student> input) {
    return input.stream().filter(s -> s.getPoints() > 50).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But you may notice that it needs change in interface's declaration also to have same types.